# Why is linear velocity not rad*m /s?

Tags: physics, dimensional-analysis

Considering that angular velocity is: 
$w = \frac{2\pi}{t} \frac{[rad]}{[s]}$; 
and that linear velocity is: 
$ v = w \frac{[rad]}{[s]} \times r[m]$;

 
I would expect linear velocity to be expressed as $v = x\frac{[rad]\times[m]}{[s]}$; 
but, as far as I know, it's always expressed in meters per second. 
My question is: Where do the radians disappear to?

Comment: The radians were never there. That is, they only exist when written down so that the meaning is clear, not in a dimensional analysis sense. Recall that the definition of an angle (in radians) is as the ratio between the length of the arc of and the radius of a sector subtended by that angle. Thus the dimension (i.e. Units) of an angle is length divided by length which is nothing (dimensionless).

Comment: Okay, that does make sense.

Comment: I sometime used to think $r$ not as the radius but as the circular lenght percurred per radian on the circle, so it is natural for it to have the dimension of $[m]\over[rad]$.

Comment: What do you mean, @N74 ? Do you have a graphical expression of it, because I quite don't get it.

Comment: Just draw an arc of length $r$ on the circumference... Usually you write $s=r\theta$ but $r$ is a segment and $s$ is an arc. I just used to imagine that also $r$ is an arc and that I could make a ratio between two arcs ($r$ and $s$) on the same circumference.

Comment: @N74 I see, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, *radian* is a dimensionless physical quantity. So, mentioning it while mentioning the unit of any physical quantity is not a big deal. Just like, for the angular velocity or angular frequency $\omega$, you have the unit $rad/s$ or rather $s^{-1}$, since the unit in both cases is $\mathrm{Hz}$ (hertz).

Comment: I get this, but I'm getting to the point of "not just do it because it's easier to comprehend"

Comment: @mazunki Sorry I didn't get what you exactly mean....

Comment: So you're saying radians is saying nothing at all. I don't get that. It makes no sense to me.

Comment: @mazunki That's not exactly what I meant. I have re-phrased it a bit. Please check it and inform me if its okay now.

Comment: @mazunki Radian obviously has a physical meaning and has contexts of use. But while considering a physical unit, you need not care much because its just a ratio, it does'nt affect the unit.

Comment: So it would have some influence at the point of converting it to a segment of an arc, or a quarter of an orbit; but not at general use. Is that it? @SchrodingersCat

Comment: @mazunki Yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider that $r$ is not strictly the radius, but the conversion factor between the angular speed and the linear speed, in $\frac{[m]}{[rad]}$.

Now imagine that the angles are counted in degrees. You would need to use

$w = \frac{360}{t} \frac{[°]}{[s]}$;

$ v = w \frac{[°]}{[s]} \times r'\frac{[m]}{[°]}$

where

$r'\frac{[m]}{[°]}=\frac{2\pi}{360}r\frac{[m]}{[rad]}$.